# Special tridiagonal matrix name and property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, tridiagonal-matrices

I was wondering if there is a special name for the following kind of tridiagonal matrices ? And if yes, are there any books or articles which talk about their properties ?

\begin{pmatrix}
 \alpha_1 & \beta_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \beta_{n-1} & \alpha_2 & \ddots & 0 \\
 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \beta_{n-1} \\
 0 & 0 & \beta_1 & \alpha_n
\end{pmatrix}

(basically the lower diagonal is reversed compared to the upper diagonal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any specific literature on it, but the closest terminology I would have to describe what you proposed would be a "centrosymmetric tridiagonal matrix".

In page of the following document (p.5) you can find a similar matrix in Eq. (2.5) to what you are looking for: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81151355.pdf

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot :) That answers my question!

Comment: In order to be a "centrosymmetric tridiagonal matrix" the main diagonal would need to be *palindromic" (the same values if reversed from upper left to lower right).